# %1 is not a valid win32 application during installation of.net framework 4.7.2

Tags: .net-framework

I am trying to install .net framework 4.7.2 to my D laptop (win10-64bit).

After I executed the .exe file

The installation failed almost immediately.

Dialog showed the reason "%1 is not a valid win32 application"

I copied the last part of the log file in below.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Logs:

```
OS Version = 10.0.16299, SP = 0.0, Platform 2
OS Description = Future OS - x64 Enterprise Edition 
MSI = 5.0.16299.967
Windows servicing = 10.0.16299.961
CommandLine = C:\83edfb00092ae48c41008fdd\\Setup.exe /x86 /x64 /web
TimeZone = W. Europe Standard Time
Initial LCID = 1040
Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
Operation: Installing
Package Name = Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 Setup
Package Version = 4.7.03081
User Experience Data Collection Policy: Disabled
Number of applicable items: 6
Exe (C:\83edfb00092ae48c41008fdd\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
Exe (C:\83edfb00092ae48c41008fdd\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
Exe (C:\83edfb00092ae48c41008fdd\Windows10.0-KB4073120-x64.cab) failed with 0xc1 - (null).
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x000000C1) (Elapsed time: 0 00:01:19).
```

Comment: Can you provide the web page where you found the installer?

Comment: Can you provide the contents of `dd_SetupUtility.txt`? Have you changed the folder location of the TEMP and TMP environment variables?